# Setting locale in flutter integration test using integration_test package

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I'm trying to put together a test using the [integration_test](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/e4b55a496389030d70b756a47a0fc7af98c71710/packages/integration_test) package that sets a particular locale before running the test. I tried the following (which is close to what works in WidgetTests):

```dart
    await tester.binding.setLocale('en', 'US');
    app.main();
    await tester.idle();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // The app is still using the default locale of the phone...
```

Does this need to be set in the driver? Here's my current setup in the driver:

```dart
  // Some adb commands for granting permissions...
  print('Starting test.');
  final FlutterDriver driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  final String data = await driver.requestData(
    null,
    timeout: const Duration(minutes: 1),
  );
  await driver.close();
  // Some more adb commands to revoke permissions.
```

That doesn't seem to work.

I found [this issue here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27785), but it's not using the `integration_test` package and thus has a different setup altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to localize my integration tests by wrapping my target widget in the `Localizations` widget.  Something like:

```
class WidgetTestWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetTestWrapper({
    Key? key,
    required this.locale,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final Locale locale;

  static const localizationsDelegates = <LocalizationsDelegate>[
    S.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Localizations(
          locale: locale,
          delegates: localizationsDelegates,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I pass in the desired `Locale` for the test in the call to `runApp`.

For example, for Spanish US (es-US):

```
runApp(WidgetTestWrapper(locale: const Locale('es', 'US'), child: widgetUnderTest));
```